# Magento 2 : Exclude CSS from merged file just for the homepage

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I have merge and minify CSS enabled and I would like to know if is there a way to exclude a specific CSS file from the final merged file, but only for the homepage?

I know how to remove a CSS file from the header via XML layout...

```
<remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
```

But can you remove/exclude this from the final compiled CSS file, just for the homepage?

Thanks!

Comment: for my knowledge is no way

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anybody (using Magento 2.1.4), I managed to do this by first adding my CSS file to the exclude list in my **view.xml**

```
<exclude>
    <item type="file">Module_Name::css/stylesheet.css</item>
</exclude>
```

I then created a new **cms_index_index.xml** and put it in

**app/design/frontend/name/theme-name/Magento_Cms/layout**

Then added this to remove the file from the homepage...

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <remove src="Module_Name::css/stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
```

I thought this would mean that the file is then not minified and merged for all other pages, but no... it still appears in my merged and minified master CSS file for all other pages (except the homepage)